# Simulating the left/right sliding animation transition

Tags: android

I want to port my application on all Android devices, and I want to have the right/left animation on the activities transition on all Android platform versions. I know that this feature is implemented in the 2.0 version. How can I implement this feature for the lower versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate it on lower versions by using ViewFlipper for example, but I would not suggest it if you have a lot of View elements on your UI because this requires all the Activities' code to be merged into a single Activity. With a lot of Views you'll max-out the CPU/GPU limits pretty easily. All you get is messy code and bloated XML files.

This is the effect - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZTiJmclaRc

My suggestion - just stick to what the platform API version offers by default and don't rape the hardware.

Comment: So this is the only way? By using a view flipper?

Comment: As far as I see it, this is the simplest way of doing it since the "slide-in/slide-out" animated transition between Activities is not a default implementation when developing for 1.5 and 1.6 API versions.